# Use collidelist in class

Tags: python, list, pygame, collision

I have created a class to create rectangles and put them in a list . I don't want them to collide so I use collidelist but it isn't working.rectangles are still colliding .

I also want rectangles to move down and change x position when hit a specific point ,

I can do that but I am not sure if it is preventing collidelist from working

Look the code below for more clarification.

```
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *
import time 
pygame.init()
a = 255,255,255
b = 0,0,0
c = 80,255,0
d = 0,125,125
r1 = (b,c,d)
r = random.choice(r1)
p_x = 500
p_y = 1399
width = 500
height = 1890

display = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
title = pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = False
exit_game = False

x = random.randrange(10,900)
y = random.randrange(10,900)

sy = 10
w = random.randrange(40,90)
h = random.randrange(40,90)

rectangles =[]

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self ,color ,x,y,w,h):
        self.c = color
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.w = w
        self.h = h
        self.rect =pygame.Rect(self.x ,self.y ,self.w ,self.h)
        
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(display , self.c ,(self.x ,self.y ,self.w,self.h))
        
        self.y += sy
        if self.y > height:
                self.y = -25
                self.x = random.randint(10,900)
                return self.rect
        return self.rect
                
        
    
                
            
            


for count in range(5):
    r_c = random.randint(0,255) , random.randint(0,255) , random.randint(0,255) 
    
    r_x = random.randint(10,900)
    r_y = random.randint(10,79)
    r_w = random.randint(60,100) 
    r_h = random.randint(40,80) 
    
    
    rectangle = Rectangle(r_c ,r_x,r_y,r_w,r_h)
    rectangles.append(rectangle)

    
    
    
    

while not run:
    display.fill(a)
    p =pygame.draw.rect(display,c,(p_x ,p_y ,56,56))
    
    

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit_game = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                p_x -= 60
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                p_x += 60
                
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        if rectangle.rect.collidelist(rectangles) > -1:     
            rectangle.draw()

        

    
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`collidelist()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist) evaluates the collisions between a singe [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect) object and a list of `pygame.Rect` objects.
Remove the attributes `.x`,  `.y`, `.w` and `.h` from the class, but add an new method update:

```py
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, w, h):
        self.c = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += sy
        if self.rect.y > height:
            self.rect.y = -25
            self.rect.x = random.randint(10,900)
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, self.c, self.rect)
```

Before the collision test you have to generate a list of `pygame.Rect` objects. Since each rectangle is in the list, the collision test will always find at leas one rectangle (itself). Use [`collidelistall()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelistall) and test if the number of colliding rectangles is less than 2:

```py
while not run:
    # [...]

    for rectangle in rectangles:
        rectangle.update()
        rectlist = [r.rect for r in rectangles]
        if len(rectangle.rect.collidelistall(rectlist)) < 2:     
            rectangle.draw()
```

---

Anyway, I recommend to create rectangles, which are not intersecting. At initialization:

```py
rectangles = []        
rectlist = []           
for count in range(5):
    r_c = random.randint(0,255) , random.randint(0,255) , random.randint(0,255) 
    
    create_new = True
    while create_new:
        r_x = random.randint(10,900)
        r_y = random.randint(10,79)
        r_w = random.randint(60,100) 
        r_h = random.randint(40,80) 
        rectangle = Rectangle(r_c, r_x,r_y,r_w,r_h)
        create_new = rectangle.rect.collidelist(rectlist) > -1
    
    rectangles.append(rectangle)
    rectlist.append(rectangle.rect)
```

And in the method `update` of the class `Rectangle`:

```py
class Rectangle:
    # [...]

    def update(self, rectangles):
        self.rect.y += sy
        if self.rect.y > height:
            rectlist = [r.rect for r in rectangles if r != self]
            self.rect.y = -25
            self.rect.x = random.randint(10,900)
            while self.rect.collidelist(rectlist) > -1:
                self.rect.x = random.randint(10,900)
```

---

Complete Example:

```py
import pygame
import random
from pygame.locals import *
import time 
pygame.init()
a = 255,255,255
b = 0,0,0
c = 80,255,0
d = 0,125,125
r1 = (b,c,d)
r = random.choice(r1)
p_x = 500
p_y = 1399
width = 500
height = 1890

display = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
title = pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

run = False
exit_game = False

sy = 10

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, w, h):
        self.c = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)

    def update(self, rectangles):
        self.rect.y += sy
        if self.rect.y > height:
            rectlist = [r.rect for r in rectangles if r != self]
            self.rect.y = -25
            self.rect.x = random.randint(10,900)
            while self.rect.collidelist(rectlist) > -1:
                self.rect.x = random.randint(10,900)
    
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(display, self.c, self.rect)

rectangles = []        
rectlist = []           
for count in range(5):
    r_c = random.randint(0,255) , random.randint(0,255) , random.randint(0,255) 
    
    create_new = True
    while create_new:
        r_x = random.randint(10,900)
        r_y = random.randint(10,79)
        r_w = random.randint(60,100) 
        r_h = random.randint(40,80) 
        rectangle = Rectangle(r_c, r_x,r_y,r_w,r_h)
        create_new = rectangle.rect.collidelist(rectlist) > -1
    
    rectangles.append(rectangle)
    rectlist.append(rectangle.rect)

while not run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit_game = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_q:
                p_x -= 60
            if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                p_x += 60
                
    for rectangle in rectangles[:]:
        rectangle.update(rectangles)
    
    display.fill(a)
    p = pygame.draw.rect(display,c,(p_x ,p_y ,56,56))
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        rectangle.draw()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
    
pygame.quit()
quit()
```